# Fix ownership of directory on Ubuntu 20 server

Tags: permissions, sudo, wordpress

My client's WordPress website is hosted at Digital Ocean. I have set the permissions they recommended on this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack), but have run into permission issues accessing the example.com directory on the server using SSH. When I try to access the directory using `cd example.com`, the following message is displayed: `-bash: cd: example.com: Permission denied`.

I have run the `stat` command on the example.com directory and the output is included below.

```
File: example.com
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 258961      Links: 5
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (   33/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
```

I am also unable to connect via SFTP using the SSH user I created when setting up the Droplet. The following message is displayed by Transmit on my MacBook Pro: Make sure you have permission to modify this file.

If I change the directory permissions to `sudo chown -R example:example /var/www/example.com` SFTP connects, but the WordPress installation does not work correctly.

What do I need to change in order for WordPress, SSH, and SFTP to work correctly with the proper permissions?

Comment: I would suggest to create a group or use an existing group and set all users used in those 3 to that group. Then set permissions to include that group (so use chmod 770) . Probably the easiest fix.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: @Rinzwind I am new to server management and adjusting permissions. Do you have an example or a reference page I could use? Cheers

Comment: @MikeHermary see if the answer gets you started. If there are issues leave a comment I will try to update the answer. I am a fan of keeping edits separate from the actual files (as that circumvents the problem you face ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Generic permissions for website files:

```
chown apache:apache -R * # change to the user and owner set for apache
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # directory permissions: rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # file permissions: rw-r--r--
```

The WP hardening [page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) states:

> All files should be owned by your user account, and should be writable by you. Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be writable by the web server, if your hosting set up requires it, that may mean those files need to be group-owned by the user account used by the web server process.

- `/` The root WordPress directory: all files should be writable only by your user account, except .htaccess if you want WordPress to automatically generate rewrite rules for you.
- `/wp-admin/` The WordPress administration area: all files should be writable only by your user account.
- `/wp-includes/` The bulk of WordPress application logic: all files should be writable only by your user account.
- `/wp-content/` User-supplied content: intended to be writable by your user account and the web server process.

Within `/wp-content/` you will find:

- `/wp-content/themes/` Theme files. If you want to use the built-in theme editor, all files need to be writable by the web server process. If you do not want to use the built-in theme editor, all files can be writable only by your user account.
- `/wp-content/plugins/` Plugin files: all files should be writable only by your user account.
- Other directories that may be present with `/wp-content/` should be documented by whichever plugin or theme requires them. Permissions may vary.

So `cd` into the Wordpress directory and do:

```
chown $USER:$USER  -R * # Let your useraccount be owner
chown www-data:www-data wp-content # Let apache be owner of wp-content
```

- the last one is subjective as it depends on how you want to use it.

Now all WP files you can directly update through ssh and ftp using your username.

This will probably work (I used my cloud instance but I do not have WP)

---

My personal take:

NEVER directly update webserver files but do it indirectly and have the system itself do the updating. If you upload file to a specific directory you can upload all files you want as your user without needing to watch permissions

- duplicate your website to for instance `/home/$USER/website/`
- Use those files to edit
- Then create a script that makes a backup and copies these files over to your actual website -without- changing permissions.
- The 2 commands to do this look like this (adjust to your situation; I used broad selections (ie. the whole website)):

  ```
  tar cvfz /u/backups/"$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p").tar.gz"  /var/www/
  sudo cp -rp /home/$USER/website/ /var/www/
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have changed the permissions with what you posted above, but am now experiencing the FTP notice when trying to update plugins. I have tried using $USER:$USER and www-data:www-data for ownership of wp-content, but neither solve the issue. All other directories and files are owned by $USER.